# Jquery - Disabling text field and re enabling fields

Tags: jquery, input, field

Is there a jquery function to limit one submission on a text field once it has been submitted? And once the user deletes the existing information in that field should they change their mind, the submit button will become re enabled and they will be able to resubmit their text.

For example:

-User is making a tshirt
-Tshirt product only allows one line of text on it
-Once they insert text in the field, the field is disabled
-Field can be reenabled if they delete or reset text field.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: No one function does that, no.

Comment: @nullability theres no jquery way to make it after submit, it disables the field so they cant change it?

Comment: If you disable the text field they cannot go back and update the text. You would have to create a separate control, like a button, that would enable the button. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9yzvkm68/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a listening event to limit the number of characters entered, and disable the field once they reach that limit. Then maybe a reset button to start over.

Ex:

```
//this function would freeze the field if they reach a char max.
//I would suggest changing the field color tho, and disabling the
//submit button if they exceed the max
$("#tshirt_text").keyup(function(){
    var content = $(this).val();
    if( content.length = 26 ) { //or whatever your char max is
        $(this).prop( "disabled", true );
    }
});

//this function could freeze the field when it loses focus 
$("#tshirt_text").blur(function(){
    $(this).prop( "disabled", true );
}

//clear the field onclick
$("#clearButton").click(function(){
    $("#thsirt_text").prop( "disabled", false );
}
```